# A script on this page is causing Internet Explorer to run slowly

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, performance

I have jQuery code:

```
...
var poleVstupu= {id:['31'],platny:['1'],datum:['2013-08-05 20:23:38'], ... };

for(var poleName in poleVstupu)
{
    $('[name='+poleName+']').val(poleVstupu[poleName]).change();
}
...
```

in Firefox this code works fine, but in IE8 it throws `...run slowly` message. If I run IE built-in debugger, after `...run slowly` message it throws `object doesn't support this property or method` , but if I set breakpoint at `$('[name='+poleName ...` line, it doesn't show `object doesn't ...` message.

what can I do to process code faster and prevent displaying `...run slowly` message?

Comment: Selection by name isn't very optimal. It may help to limit the search to surrounding element such as the form. Or use IDs instead. Are you using a current version of jQuery? How many items does your object/form have?

Comment: What almost may help, would be not to use jQuery.

Comment: Finally: Do you have a change event handler, and what does it do?

Comment: why it isn't optimal? where is the problem? I can't use 'form' surrounding because I want change only some elements from the form (defined by 'poleVstupu' array). I can use ID, but in every element there will be name and ID attributes (little bit messy). I'm using jquery-1.8.2. My form has about 300 items (it depends. it's dynamic), but with the name selector I'm changing only a part.

Comment: ... If you recomending not to use jQuery, how the code will looks? ...and change() is used to change SELECT items. selected item affecting another form output. change is used for all (inputs too). I thing it isn't problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm responding to the comments in this answer, because it will be longer and include code, but it most likely won't be an answer.

---

There is a good chance that the browser doesn't index the `name` attribute, so it has to loop through  every single element in the document each time to find a matching name. If you limit the search to the form, you'll may have a better performance. Example:

```
var form = $("#form_id");

for(var poleName in poleVstupu)
{
    form.find('[name='+poleName+']').val(poleVstupu[poleName]).change();
}
```

---

A (partial) non-jQuery solution could be to access the form elements directly from DOM. Example:

```
var form = $("#form_id")[0]; // Get the DOM reference of the form

for(var poleName in poleVstupu)
{
    jQuery(form.elements[poleName]).val(poleVstupu[poleName]).change();
}
```

---

It may also help you'd loop over the form elements instead the object. Example:

```
var form = $("#form_id")[0]; // Get the DOM reference of the form

for (var i = 0, len = form.elements.length; i < len; i++)
{
    var element = form.elements[i];
    if (typeof poleVstupu[element.name] !== "undefined")
      jQuery(element).val(poleVstupu[element.name]).change();
}
```

---

The performance of jQuery increases with every version. Can't you use 1.10.x or even 2.x?

---

How is the performance if you leave out `.change()`?

---

**EDIT:**

On non form elements `name` is invalid anyway, so you shouldn't be using that. I'd use the id and set a class on all elements where you need to do this:

```
$(".change-html").each(function() {
  if (typeof poleVstupu[this.id] !== "undefined") {
    $(this).html(poleVstupu[element.name]);
  }
});
```

Or if you can't use the id, for eaxmple, because you have duplicates, use a [`data-` attribute](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/).

```
<p data-change-html="your_name"></p>

$("[data-change-html]").each(function() {
  var element = $(this);
  var name = element.data("change-html");
  if (typeof poleVstupu[name] !== "undefined") {
    element.html(poleVstupu[name]);
  }
});
```

(But the latter won't be very fast mostlikey).

Comment: my page is almost a big form, so I tried last example and there are results: old code (with change())->85 sec, new code(without change)->11 sec, new code (with change())-> 15 sec, new code (with jQ 1.10 and change())-> 18 sec, new code (with jQ 2 and change())-> errors->not defined JSON,jQuery... so your last example is very good. I didn't know about browser indexing before. thanks

Comment: You can probably speed it up more, if you optimize the your change event handler. jQuery 2 doesn't support IE8, because it is very outdated. You should also consider not supporting IE8.

Comment: Also, more speed up would be to not use `.val()` for jQuery, because it supports all the different form field types (text, checkbox, select, etc.). Whats form field types do you need to support?

Comment: Finally, you may also want to consider redesigning your whole application. A form with 300 fields is not only a speed problem, but also a usability problem. I can't imagine that the user wants/needs all those form elements at once.

Comment: yes, I agree with you. It's an enormous form, but my chief is crazy and he think somebody will be filling this form :-D (that's his problem). I had this form divided into parts(formToWizard.js), but there were some coherence problems. I have a text, check, select inputs there... Bud maybe the problem is not here. I have tried 'AOL Pagetest' and here is the result [link](http://www.2i.cz/1f00f2d80b) (please click on image). I don't undestand why is there a big pause and why the browser loading folder at the end.

Comment: I have one extra issue. somewhere I need to insert values to non form elements ( `$(element).html('something')` ) and I can't use `form.elements` . is there faster way than by jQuery `name` selector?

Comment: See edit. Also I believe IE8 has a profiler built in it's developer tools. I've never used it, so I can't tell you how to.

Comment: ok. I don't understand IE profiler. Maybe in future. Thanks for your edited solution. It looks better and faster than mine which is not wholly right (but works IE and FF):    `var elementy = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
    for (var i=0, len=elementy.length; i<len; i++)
    {
     var element = elementy[i];
     if (typeof poleVstupu[element.getAttribute("name")] !== "undefined")
       $(element).html("<b>"+poleVstupu[element.getAttribute("name")]+"</b>");
    } `

Answer (score 0):

Are you running your IE inside a virtual machine? If so, make sure you give the virtual machine enough RAM allocation and CPU power (if settable) so scripts can run using a significant portion of your computer's abilities.

Comment: do you mean something like java virtual machine? no, I have windows xp and run IE directly from there